# Await for file to load, then run a function on each 'line' but wait for the return on each line

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, puppeteer

I have been trying to understand Promises and I'm hitting a brick wall.

==Order I want the code to run==

1. I need a .txt file to load each line into an array.
2. WAIT for this to happen.
3. Run a Function on each entry that returns and array.
4. WAIT for each index of the array to be processed before doing the next.

==My Functions==

1. Call this function to start the program.

```
async function start(){
    var data = await getData();
    console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        console.log(await searchGoogle(data[i]));
    }

}
```

1. 'await' for the data from getData

```
async function getData(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        fs.readFile('./thingsToGoogle.txt', function(err, data) {
            if(err) throw err;
            var array = data.toString().split("\n");
            resolve(array); 
        });
    });
}
```

1. Then call searchGoogle on each index in the array.

```
async function searchGoogle(toSearch) {
    (async() => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
        await page.type('input[name=q]', toSearch);
        try {
            console.log('Setting Search' + toSearch);           
            await page.evaluate(() => {
                let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('gNO89b');
                for (let element of elements)
                    element.click();
            });
            await page.waitForNavigation();         
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }

        try {
            console.log("Collecting Data");
            const[response] = await Promise.all([
                        page.waitForNavigation(),
                        await page.click('.rINcab'),
                    ]);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error2: " + err)
        }

        let test = await page.$$('.LC20lb');
        // console.log(test);
        allresults = [];
        for (const t of test) {
            const label = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, t);
            if (label != "") {
                allresults.push(label);
            }
        }
        await browser.close();
        resolve(allresults);

    })();
}
```

The problem is that this does not work. it does not wait for the file to load.

[Picture of Node JS output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrR2u.png)

Hopefully the screen shot has uploaded, but you can see it stacking the SearchGoogle function console.logs;

```
console.log('Setting..')
console.log('Setting..')
console.log('Collecting..')
console.log('Collecting..')
```

When it should be

```
console.log('Setting..')
console.log('Collecting..')
console.log('Setting..')
console.log('Collecting..')
```

This is the 'first' time sort of dealing with promises, i have done a lot of reading up on them and done bits of code to understand them, however when I have tried to apply this knowledge I am struggling. Hope someone can help.

-Peachman-

Comment: I think the post is missing the problem statement. What's the problem again?

Comment: @Joseph just amended my problem. basically it doesn't do it... :(

Comment: Is the point here to just end up with an array of processed lines in order?  If so, you don't have to do as much waiting as you have in your question.  You've over specified a more complicated set of requirements.

Comment: @jfriend00 the problem comes when I have a document of thousands and thousands of entries. I cant process all of them at once and the search Google function takes a few seconds to process one entry. Hence why I want to do one, wait till it's done, do another, and wait till that's done ect...

Comment: Probably the system would perform best if you were processing N entries at once where you could configure what N would be, but I would guess somewhere in the 10-20 range.  Then you wouldn't be overwhelming your system resources, but also wouldn't be spending most of your CPU idling waiting for a network response.

Answer (score 1):

## Queue with concurrent Limit (using `p-queue`)

You need a queue with concurrency limit. You will read every single line and add them to a queue. We will be using [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line) and [p-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-queue) module for this.

First, create a queue with concurrency of 1.

```
const {default: PQueue} = require('p-queue');
const queue = new PQueue({concurrency: 1});
```

Then, create our reader instance.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('your-input-file.txt')
});
```

For every line of the file, add an entry to the queue.

```
rl.on('line', (line) => {
  console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
  queue.add(() => searchGoogle(line));
});
```

That's it! If you want to process 10 lines at once, just change the concurrency line. It will still read one line at a time, but the queue will limit how many `searchGoogle` is invoked.

[image]

## Optional Fixes: Async Await

Your code has the following structure,

```
async yourFunction(){
  (async()=>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    // ... rest of the code
  })()
}
```

While this might run as intended, you will have a hard time debugging because you will be creating an anonymous function every time you run `yourFunction`.

The following is enough.

```
async yourFunction(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    // ... rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to process them that lets you process N URLs at a time where you can adjust the value of N.  My guess is that you want it set to a value of between 5 and 20 in order to keep your CPU busy, but not use too many server resources.

Here's an outline of how it works:

1. It uses the line-by-line module to read a file line by line and (unlike the built-in readline interface), this module pauses `line` events when you call `.pause()` which is important in this implementation.
2. It maintains a `numInFlight` counter that tells you how many lines are in the midst of processing.
3. You set a `maxInFlight` constant to the maximum number of lines you want to be processed in parallel.
4. It maintains a `resultCntr` that helps you keep results in the proper order.
5. It creates the readline interface and establishes a listener for the `line` event.  This will start the stream flowing with `line` events.
6. On each `line` event, we increment our `numInFlight` counter.  If we have reached the maximum number allowed in flight, we pause the readline stream so it won't produce any more `line` events.  If we haven't reached the max in flight yet, then more `line` events will flow until we do reach the max.
7. We pass that line off to your existing `searchGoogle()` function.
8. When that line is done processing, we save the result in the appropriate spot in the array, decrement the `numInFlight` counter and resume the stream (in case it was previously paused).
9. We check if we're all done (by checking if `numInFlight` is `0` and if we've reached the end of our file).  If we are done, resolve the master promise with the results.
10. If we're not all done, then there will either be more `line` events coming or more `searchGoogle()` functions in flight that will finish, both of which will check again to see if we're done.
11. Note that the way this is designed to work is that errors on any given URL are just put into the result array (the error object is in the array) and processing continues on the rest of the URLs with an eventual resolved promise.  Errors while reading the input file will terminate processing and reject the return promise.

Here's the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Readline = require('line-by-line');

function searchAll(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const rl = new Readline(file);
        // set maxInFlight to something between 5 and 20 to optimize performance by
        // running multiple requests in flight at the same time without
        // overusing memory and other system resources.
        const maxInFlight = 1;

        let numInFlight = 0;
        let resultCntr = 0;
        let results = [];
        let doneReading = false;

        function checkDone(e) {
            if (e) {
                reject(e);
            } else if (doneReading && numInFlight === 0) {
                resolve(results);
            }
        }

        rl.on('line', async (url) => {
            if (url) {
                let resultIndex = resultCntr++;
                try {
                    ++numInFlight;
                    if (numInFlight >= maxInFlight) {
                        // stop flowing line events when we hit maxInFlight
                        rl.pause();
                    }
                    let result = await searchGoogle(url);
                    // store results in order
                    results[resultIndex] = result;
                } catch(e) {
                    // store error object as result
                    results[resultIndex] = e;
                } finally {
                    --numInFlight;
                    rl.resume();
                    checkDone();
                }
            }
        }).on('end', () => {
            // all done reading here, may still be some processing in flight
            doneReading = true;
            checkDone();
        }).on('error', (e) => {
            doneReading = true;
            checkDone(e);
        });    
    });
}
```

FYI, you can set `maxInFlight` to a value of `1` and it will read process the URLs one at a time, but the whole point of writing this type of function is so that you can likely get better performance by setting it to a value higher than `1` (I'm guessing 5-20).

Comment: @peachman19917 - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.